# Get value of symbol without evaluating it

Tags: common-lisp

It is possible to get value of the symbol unevaluated like this:

```
(let ((form '(+ 1 2))) `',form)
```

This expression evaluates to the following:

```
'(+ 1 2)
```

Is there some way to do the same thing but without using backquote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the longer syntax if you want. Let's see how your form is read and evaluated, step-by-step.

```
(let ((form '(+ 1 2))) `',form)
```

Apostrophe is quote:

```
(let ((form '(+ 1 2))) `(quote ,form))
```

Backquote/comma (quasiquote) is a shorthand for building data:

```
(let ((form '(+ 1 2))) (list 'quote form))
```

Evaluate the `let` binding, which associates `form` with its value, literally the list `(+ 1 2)`, inside the lexical environment of this expression:

```
(list 'quote form)
```

Te above builds a list made of the `quote` symbol and the current value bound to `form`. The above results in a list starting with quote and a sublist, which prints as follows:

```
(quote (+ 1 2))
```

... which admits this simpler representation:

```
'(+ 1 2)
```

So you can use `(list 'quote form)` if you prefer, but this is not much different.

Comment: `(list 'quote (+ 1 2))` is confusing. What does that mean. Why is the first one quoted, and the second one not?

Comment: @RainerJoswig This was supposed to be the representation at mid-step of the evaluation, when trying to substitute `form` with its value. I agree that it was deeply confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
(let ((form '(+ 1 2))) (list 'quote form))
```

If `form` is really a constant:

```
(list 'quote (list '+ '1 '2))
```

The quotes on `1` and `2` are redundant, since they're literals, but they are informative and are already there in case you replace then with actual expressions.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. So any backquoted expression can be substituted by combination of `list`, `cons` and `append`, right?

Comment: Yes, [the backquote syntax](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) is specified to be equivalent to the use of `list`, `append`, `nconc` and `quote`, or any equivalent expression, such as by the use of `cons`, `list*`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
(let ((form '(+ 1 2))) `',form)
```

You ask:

> It is possible to get value of the symbol unevaluated...

Actually this not really what it does. By default Common Lisp has local variables using lexical bindings, not symbols having values. Above `form` computes the value of the variable `form`, not of the symbol `form`. The value of `form` is the list `(+ 1 2)`. With the backquoted `quote`, you put a list `(quote ...)` around it. Which gets printed as `(QUOTE (+ 1 2))` or `'(+ 1 2)`.

Note that Common Lisp has no way to get from a symbol to the value of a lexical binding. In the source code symbols denote variables, but at runtime we have lexical bindings and not associations from symbols to values.